# Facebook login PHP SKD

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login

Mission: To get successful login to Facebook from my website, returning user ID and eventually, email etc. to add to my db database.

I downloaded the latest 4.0.0 SKD PHP from developers.facebook.com and uploaded it to my file manager.

I'm using code found on GitHub: http://packetcode.com/rd/6e20a9

Please see code below on `index.php`

```
<?

/* INCLUSION OF LIBRARY FILEs*/
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
    require_once( 'lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');


/* USE NAMESPACES */

    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
    use Facebook\GraphUser;
    use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
    use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
    use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
    use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
/*PROCESS*/

    //1.Stat Session
     session_start();

     //2.Use app id,secret and redirect url 
    $app_id = 'my id';
     $app_secret = 'my secret';
     $redirect_url='my url';

     //3.Initialize application, create helper object and get fb sess
     FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);
     $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
     $sess = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    //4. if fb sess exists echo name 
        if(isset($sess)){
            //create request object,execute and capture response
        $request = new FacebookRequest($sess, 'GET', '/me');
        // from response get graph object
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
        // use graph object methods to get user details
        $name= $graph->getName();
        echo "hi $name";
    }else{
        //else echo login
        echo '<a href='.$helper->getLoginUrl().'>Login with facebook</a>';
    }

    ?>
```

I've copied the video tutorial bit for bit and it works when he does it so I'm lost as to what I'm doing wrong.

When I clicked the link "Login with facebook", it took me through to facebook, asked for permission where I clicked "play now", and then it redirected me back to my url, however with the following error.

Now everytime I click the "login with facebook" link it just takes me straight to the error..

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message 'Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request' in /home/*****/public_html/lib/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php:104 Stack trace: #0 /home/*****/public_html/lib/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php(268): Facebook\FacebookRequestException::create('{"error":{"mess...', Object(stdClass), 400) #1 /home/****/public_html/lib/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php(146): Facebook\FacebookRequest->execute() #2 /home/*****/public_html/index.php(48): Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper->getSessionFromRedirect() #3 {main} thrown in /home/*****/public_html/lib/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php on line 104
```

After looking on here and Google I can't seem to find out the cause of this error and how to fix it.

Comment: Are you sure no answers provided by the [Search function](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Error+validating+verification+code.+Please+make+sure+your+redirect_uri+is+identical+to+the+one+you+used+in+the+OAuth+dialog+request) can't help you?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the answer.

Thought I'd post it here to let others know who may be struggling.

Verrrry simple..

make sure there is a / at the end of your redirect url..

for example,

http://mytestsite.com/